# Issues writing file metadata with Java nio

Tags: java, file, metadata, nio

I'm looking to add a custom metadata tag to any type of file using  functionality from java.nio.file.Files. I have been able to read metadata correctly, but am having issues whenever I try to set metadata.

I've tried to set a custom metadata element with a plain string using Files.setAttribute with the following

```
    Path photo = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\some\\picture\\path\\2634.jpeg");
    try{
        BasicFileAttributes attrs = Files.readAttributes(photo, BasicFileAttributes.class);
        Files.setAttribute(photo, "user:tags", "test");
        String attribute = Files.getAttribute(photo, "user:tags").toString();
        System.out.println(attribute);
    }
    catch (IOException ioex){
        ioex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but end up with the following error :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.nio.ByteBuffer

if I try to cast that string to a ByteBuffer like so

```
    Path photo = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\some\\picture\\path\\2634.jpeg");
    try{
        BasicFileAttributes attrs = Files.readAttributes(photo, BasicFileAttributes.class);
        Files.setAttribute(photo, "user:tags", ByteBuffer.wrap(("test").getBytes("UTF-8")));
        String attribute = Files.getAttribute(photo, "user:tags").toString();
        System.out.println(attribute);
    }
    catch (IOException ioex){
        ioex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

instead of outputting the text 'test', it outputs the strange character string '[B@14e3f41'

What is the proper way to convert a String to a bytebuffer and have it be convertable back into a string, and is there a more customizable way to modify metadata on a File using java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User defined attributes, that is any attribute defined by [`UserDefinedFileAttributeView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/UserDefinedFileAttributeView.html) (provided that your `FileSystem` supports them!), are readable/writable from Java as byte arrays; if a given attribute contains text content, it is then process dependent what the encoding will be for the string in question.

Now, you are using the `.{get,set}Attribute()` methods, which means that you have two options to write `user` attributes:

- either using a `ByteBuffer` like you did; or
- using a plain byte array.

What you will *read* out of it however is a byte array, always.

From the javadoc link above (emphasis mine):

> Where dynamic access to file attributes is required, the getAttribute method may be used to read the attribute value. **The attribute value is returned as a byte array (byte[]). The setAttribute method may be used to write the value of a user-defined attribute from a buffer (as if by invoking the write method), or byte array (byte[])**.

So, in your case:

- in order to *write* the attribute, obtain a byte array with the requested encoding from your string:

  ```
  final Charset utf8 = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
  final String myAttrValue = "Mémé dans les orties";
  final byte[] userAttributeValue = myAttrValue.getBytes(utf8);
  Files.setAttribute(photo, "user:tags", userAttributeValue);
  ```
- in order to *read* the attribute, you'll need to cast the result of `.getAttribute()` to a byte array, and then obtain a string out of it, again using the correct encoding:

  ```
  final Charset utf8 = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
  final byte[] userAttributeValue 
      = (byte[]) Files.readAttribute(photo, "user:tags");
  final String myAttrValue = new String(userAttributeValue, utf8);
  ```

---

A peek into the other solution, just in case...

As already mentioned, what you want to deal with is a `UserDefinedFileAttributeView`. The `Files` class allows you to obtain any `FileAttributeView` implementation using this method:

```
final UserDefinedFileAttributeView view
    = Files.getFileAttributeView(photo, UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);
```

Now, once you have this view at your disposal, you may read from, or write to, it.

For instance, here is how you would read your particular attribute; note that here we only use the attribute *name*, since the view (with name `"user"`) is already there:

```
final Charset utf8 = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
final int attrSize = view.size("tags");
final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(attrSize);
view.read("tags", buf);
return new String(buf.array(), utf8);
```

In order to write, you'll need to wrap the byte array into a `ByteBuffer`:

```
final Charset utf8 = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
final int array = tagValue.getBytes(utf8);
final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(array);
view.write("tags", buf);
```

Like I said, it gives you more control, but is more involved.

Final note: as the name pretty much dictates, user defined attributes are user defined; a given attribute for this view may, or may not, exist. It is your responsibility to correctly handle errors if an attribute does not exist etc; the JDK offers no such thing as `NoSuchAttributeException` for this kind of scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response,  it helped solved the issue, but does this mean that ANY user defined tags  of any data type I could have would have to first be encoded into a byte array on write, and decoded into the matching type any time they were meant to be read?

Comment: @PhilSimmons indeed, it means exactly that; user defined attributes can be literally anything, not only text content!

Comment: @PhilSimmons note that there is another option to read/write attributes (going through the `View`); it is a little more complicated, however

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction so I could start investigating other possibles?

Comment: @lobobabysaurus other possibilities for what exactly?

Comment: Other possiblities for reading and writing metadata to a file.  Does the other option you mentioned accomplish the exact same end with everything stored as byte array, or does it allow for more controlled manipulation?

Comment: Metadata will not be written to a file directly (in that case that would be data!). The other solution gives you more precise control but won't help the fact that what you will write/read as metadata will still be byte arrays. Now, of course, you have all the methods of `ByteBuffer` available. It really depends on what metadata you want to store.

Comment: @lobobabysaurus see comment above; not sure you saw it

Comment: @lobobabysaurus see post edit; I have added an alternative solution making use of the underlying `FileAttributeView`.